# FTPClient.listFiles is not returning time in seconds

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

```
private static void getFTPFileProperties(FTPClient client,
            String ftpLocation, String pattern) throws IOException {
    FTPFile[] fileList=null;
    fileList = client.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
    {
        FTPFile file= fileList[0];
        Calendar cal = file.getTimestamp();
        DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dateFormater.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

I have written the above function to retrieve the file details. But somehow I am retrieving the details without seconds part of the file.
I am retrieving the `lastModifiedDate` as `2013-08-08 00:00:00` where as its actual `lastModifiedDate` is `2013-08-08 12:53:27 PM`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`FTPClient.listFiles`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles()) uses the ancient `LIST` command. With the command, it's quite common that the FTP server returns a listing similar to that of the Unix `ls` command. It displays timestamps with a day precision only, for old files (older than a year).

Nowadays, you should always use the [`FTPClient.mlistDir`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistDir()), which uses the modern [`MLSD` command](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7) that always retrieves timestamps with second precision.

```
public FTPFile[] mlistDir() throws IOException
```

Of course, unless you connect to an ancient FTP server, that does not support the `MLSD` command.

Note that the `mlistDir` is supported since Apache Commons Net 3.0.